# Changing the class of an AwesomeIcon dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I have this awesome Icon

```
<i id="myIdAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

which I tried to change the class using

```
 $('myIdAwesomeIcon').addClass('fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg').removeClass('fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg');
```

something changed but the result is not the expected:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your net result is to remove the `fa` and `fa-lg` classes. If you just want to change the `toggle-on` to `toggle-off`, use `toggleClass()`, like this:

```
$('#myIdAwesomeIcon').toggleClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` for `id` selector and I recommend to use `removeClass` first and then `addClass`. Since, your css color was so light, for this example I changed the color to `red`.

```js
$('#myIdAwesomeIcon').removeClass('fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg').addClass('fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="myIdAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:red;" aria-hidden="true">ss</i>
```

Comment: Given that the OP says 'something changed, but not what they wanted', I would assume this is just a typo when transcribing the code to the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan let's us please wait for OP response on this

Answer (score 0):

`removeClass('fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg');` removes `fa`, `fa-toggle-on` and `fa-lg` in your case you need to remove and add only unique classes. Hence your code will look like as follows:

```
$('#myIdAwesomeIcon').addClass('fa-toggle-on').removeClass('fa-toggle-off');
```

Note: # for id and . for class is required as selector in jQuery.